# jquery validate not loaded requirejs

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, requirejs, unobtrusive-validation, unobtrusive-javascript

I have a main module in RequireJS:

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'jquery.validate',
    'jquery.validate.unobtrusive'
], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var validator = $("form").validate();
        if ($("#txtFirstName").val() !== "")
            validator.element("#txtFirstName");
    });
});
```

When I load this page, I get a JavaScript error:

> TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function
>   var validator = $("form").validate();**

I don't now why? All scripts are loaded:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to configure `shim` to "wire" the dependencies correctly:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'jquery': 'path-to-jquery',
    'jquery.validate': 'path-to-jquery-validate',
    'jquery.validate.unobtrusive': 'path-to-jquery-validate-unobtrusive'
  },
  shim: {
    'jquery.validate': ['jquery'],
    'jquery.validate.unobtrusive': ['jquery', 'jquery.validate']
  }
});

require(['jquery', 'jquery.validate', 'jquery.validate.unobtrusive'], function ($) {
  // your code
});
```

More details (and examples) [in the official documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) (look for the *"For "modules" that are just jQuery or Backbone plugins..."* section).